# can' t cast double to int in xml

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android studio 3.6

data binding

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:max='@{model.maxDiscountBonuses}'
            android:progress="@{(int) model.discountBonuses}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/currentBonusesTextView" />
```

But I get error.

How cast double  (`model.discountBonuses`) to int in xml?

Answer (score 2):

You should try it like this

```
<data>
    <import type="java.lang.Integer"/>
</data>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:max='@{model.maxDiscountBonuses}'
    android:progress="@{Integer.valueOf(model.discountBonuses)}"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/currentBonusesTextView" />
```